# deterministic function in Matlab for clustering

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have been using Matlab built-in kmeans function to do clustering. Due to randomness used in the algorithm, the results are different if I set seeds differently. This is a little annoying. Is there a way to reduce the discrepancy of the clustering results? Alternatively, is there a deterministic function in Matlab for clustering?

Comment: Why not just use a deterministic *initialization*? See the manual.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The only way I can think of is to use, e.g., rng(1) to set the seed.

Comment: That is a popular choice, yes. Or use the first k points. Or some fixed set of k points determined by any other method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with some methods to reduce the discrepancy of the clustering results.

1. Put 'OnlinePhase','on' in the arguments in the kmeans. This will lead to a local min which is often the global min.
2. Put 'Replicates', 5 in the arguments. Here 5 can be replaced with an even larger number. It asks Matlab to do kmeans 5 times and choose the best result.
3. Put 'MaxIter', 1000 in the arguments. This will increase the max number of iterations from the default 100 to 1000, which could, but not likely, improve the accuracy.

As long as we aim for the best outcome from kmeans, we are more likely to get consistent results.

Comment: So you didn’t try setting `'Start'` as suggested by a comment? It allows you to provide the seeds. That makes the algorithm deterministic.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I could make it deterministic by setting the 'Start'. However, this may lead to a worse clustering result. I need to balance the performance and randomness.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image processing toolbox, there are tools which use Otsu's method, which is deterministic

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method

If datain is your input data:

For 2 classes:
`threshold = graythresh(datain);`

threshold = the threshold value for splitting the data into 2 classes, normalized to [0,1]

For multiple classes:
`thresholds = multithresh(datain,N);`

N = number of thresholds

thresholds = 1xN vector of thresholds (not normalized)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal.
The k-average algorithm creates new classes after each iteration, hence the results may be different.
For example: the algorithm is to determine which fruit is an apple that has a pear. It can classify an apple as a pear, but then all apples will be pears, while all pears will be apples.